# Access Privacy > Location Services > System Services > Compass Calibration from app

Tags: ios, objective-c, arkit, compass, ios12

ARKit has a big problem in that if "Compass Calibration" is disabled in user settings, GravityAndHeading breaks, and there's no way to guide a user to turning it back on.

Further, it seems that for whatever reason, iPhone X's running iOS 12 have this turned off by default.

1. Is it possible to openUrl: Privacy > Location Services > System Services > Compass Calibration
2. Are there any other options available?